# Add Hyperlink to Excel csv file in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Hello i am making a software which gets data from an API and puts it in excel in csv format using pandas.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Certificate #", "Lab", "Shape", "Size", "Color", "Clarity", "Min", "Max", "Hgt", "Cut", "Depth", "Table", "Pol", "Sym", "Flour", "Key to Symbols", "Comments", "Type", "Rep. Date", "Stock #", "$/ct", "Rap", "Company"])
df2.to_csv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "OUTPUTS", "GiaOut_" + strftime("%d-%m-%Y") + "_" + sys.argv[1]))
```

data is a list of lists where each item is a string. i want the second column "Lab" to be a hyperlink. it should display the text "*LAB*" underlined in blue and a link behind it.

thanks

Comment: You can't save a hyperlink in a csv. It would have to be an Excel file format.

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to create a styled data frame and then only you can save it as an Excel format.
2. If you try to save it through `df.to_excel`, all your formatting will not be gonna save. Instead of this, you have to create/open an excel spreadsheet through `ExcelWriter` and have to save according to this [code](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html) snippet.